# Tips for golfing in TeaScript

Tags: tips

> TeaScript is a powerful JavaScript golfing language created by StackExchange, PPCG, user Downgoat. TeaScript compiles to JavaScript and contains many helpful features for golfing

This question is to list some [TeaScript](https://teascript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) golfing [tips](/questions/tagged/tips)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Too short description, perhaps?

Comment: (anyway. looking at the descriptions at the other tips questions, there should be a short description what the language is, and why is it interesting to golf in. otherwise it's not going to attract much interest.)

Comment: Maybe linking to a documentation which on 2nd page contains 2 dead links to the language's Web Interface, raise more suspicions than interest…

Comment: Well,, I'd expect a question like this to *either* ask about something *or* deliver some initial content (self-answer). I don't see much use in a "placeholder question". But that might be just me.

Comment: I'd advise adding your own tips to get the ball rolling

Comment: @BetaDecay I just started with it and haven't found any yet.

Comment: `many helpful features for golfing` There's definitely at least 1 tip.